# idea(64).exe "Couldn't load main class" unless run by administrator

Tags: windows-7, intellij-idea

I just lost my admin privileges on my windows 7 (company policy).  Now when I try to start idea.exe or idea64.exe I get a dialog with:

> Couldn't load main class

If I right click on the executable and "run as administrator" it works.

Maybe someone face this issue before and know what permissions need to be added to what directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that IDEA can read all its files from the installation directory and read/write all files in [config/plugins/caches](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) directories.

Comment: I define my own config, system and plugin paths via IDEA_PROPERTIES environment variable.  I pointed them to a new directory owned by my user and the problem remains.  Is there a logfile somewhere or some command line option to give me some kind of output?

Comment: Try running `idea.exe /create-i4j-log`, produced exe4j log could have some details about the problem.

Comment: I'm confused now.  I tried with /crreate-i4j-log and saw that it was searching for IDEA_JDK.  So I set it to point to my jdk.  Ran it again and it worked.  Now even without the IDEA_JDK set it work.  Can't explain, but I'm happy

Comment: `IDEA_JDK` environment variable is not required to run, JDK search sequence is as follows: 1) `IDEA_JDK` env, 2) `./jre` directory, 3) registry, 4) `JDK_HOME` env.

Comment: I know, I saw that on the logs.  I just wanted to mention that this solved the problem.  I started it once with the env var set, and from there on everything worked.

Comment: Just as a "late" FYI, my win7 workstation just got staged again, I had the same issue.  It seams starting intellij from the command line with /create-i4j-log twice fixes the issue.  Embarassed to say this, but it's all I got.